# Should the WCF service stay opened all the time?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-client

I am creating a wcf service, my wcf service now is hosted in a console application as shown below

```
 PersonService = new ServiceHost(typeof(PersonService));
 PersonService.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPersonService), binding, "http://localhost:5645/PersonService");
 PersonService.Open();
```

Then I am consuming the wcf service using the ChannelFactory class;

```
EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:5645/PersonService");
ChannelFactory<IPersonService> engineFactory = new ChannelFactory<IPersonService>(binding, endPoint);
IPersonService personChannel = engineFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Then i can use this channel to call a method such as

```
personChannel.GetPersonById("1");
personChannel.Close();
```

My Question is:

As shown in the code above, the service is always opened while the channel is closed after finishing work with it. Is this a good behavior to keep the service opened, or i should open the service and then close it on each call taking into consideration that i might have two clients calling the same service at the same time.

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your service must be kept "open" -- that's your lingo, but in reality the "Open" call puts a listener on the port.  The server must keep listening in order to know when a client wants to connect to it.  Without this, the client won't be talking to a servier that is not *listening*.

When you client is finished and got what it wants, then it can terminate (close) the connection and go away, saving resources on both sides.

This is like making a phone call.  Somebody has to sit next to the phone to "listen" for it to ring.  A client picks up a phone and call the service hotline.  The service hotline phone rings.  That person (who is "listening") picks up the phone and a "connection" (i.e. conversation) starts.

When the client is finished, he/she drops the phone and the connection is over.  However, the person manning the service hotline must continue to "listen" for new rings.

Comment: I have a web application and all my communication are doing using WCF, so i have about 50 WCF services. so it is ok to keep all the services opened all the time.

Comment: Sorry but comparing a TCP listener with a phone line is way off. The server "phone" will (almost) never become busy. It's more like a switch board, it redirects the call to another phone which answer the customers call.

Comment: @jgauffin, it isn't too bad an analogy... just not 100% correct.  Your switchboard analogy is more correct, but adds in complications that makes it a little more difficult to see the picture...

Comment: @Ghyath Serhal, I think it is OK.  Keeping 50 listeners on 50 end points do not really consume much resources, as long as those 50 listeners are not extremely active.

Comment: Your example says that only one client can be handled at the same time (since there is only one service hotline phone). That's not the case.

Comment: @jgauffin, okokok.  My analogy is more akin to a single-serve service that refuses additional connections when one is active.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it should stay open, since otherwise it would break the old proxies.

Answer (score 1):

WCF services consumes little resources and having 50 WCF services running is not a problem. But please do share the TCP port between them (the `5645` number in your case).